# What does "external angle bisector" mean? How an angle can be bisected externally?

Tags: geometry, terminology

The lines which bisect an angle and the adjacent angle made by producing one of its arms are called the *internal* and *external* bisectors of an angle.

> What does "external angle bisector" mean? How an angle can be bisected externally?

Comment: It is a bisector because it is a bisector of the adjacent angle. It is external, because it is outside the angle in question. Moreover, even if it doesn't bisect that angle, it shares some of properties with the internal bisector, so it is not that wrong to call it external bisector.

Comment: In the traditional sense, two intersecting lines determine in general an acute angle (less than $\pi/2$) and an obtuse angle, with bisector lines called the internal, resp. external line bisectors. In the case of orthogonal lines, you cannot say which is which...

Comment: You don't bisect externally, you bisect the *external angle*. Lookup the definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_and_external_angles

Answer (score 2):

When two lines cross, two angles are created: generally, one acute angle ($<90^\circ$) and one obtuse angle. Each of these angles may be bisected; so there are two bisectors (which are at right angles to each other). The description of which one is "internal" and which "external" depends entirely on which side of the intersection—that is, between which two neighbouring rays—you are viewing it from. The bisector coming towards you, or its continuation in the opposite direction, is the internal bisector.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here, $CE$ is the external angle bisector of $\angle ACD$

And $CF$ is the internal one

$CE$ can also be called the angle bisector of $\angle BCD$